# Check if backgrid cell was edited

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, editor, cell, backgrid

I just want to check if there is another way to check if a cell has been edited. Currently here is my code snippet. This is a custom cell editor.

```
Backgrid.CustomDateCell = Backgrid.DateCell.extend({
    editor: Backgrid.InputCellEditor.extend({
        attributes: {
            type: "text"
          },
        events: {},
        initialize: function(){
            Backgrid.InputCellEditor.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            var _input = this;
            $(this.el).prop('readonly', true);
            $(this.el).datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
                viewMode: "months",
                minViewMode: "months"
            });
            $(this.el).on('hide', function(e){
                var command = new Backgrid.Command({});
                _input.model.set(_input.column.get("name"), e.date);
                _input.model.trigger("backgrid:edited", _input.model, _input.column, command);
                command = _input = null;

                $(this).parent('td').addClass('cell-edited');
            });
        }
    })
});
```

The last part where i selected the parent td of the current datetimepicker manipulated and add a new class is not working. While I am trying to find a solution to get this to work, I just want to know if backgrid already has a better way to check if the cell has been edited or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I made my code to work somehow by adding a listener in the initializiation of the custom cell.

```
this.listenTo(_input.model, "backgrid:edited", function(){
                $(this.el).parent().parent().addClass('cell-edited');
            });
```

I'm still open for what i originally asked.

Thanks